# JIT not work on Django1.7 with PyPy2

Tags: python, django, pypy

I find out that Django 1.7 with pypy2 flush JIT coverage to zero randomly, using vmprof.

I don't know why, but when I run the simple Django app, JIT coverage goes back to zero randomly.

you can reproduce using https://github.com/gtlim/pypy-django. I run this code in docker container based on ubuntu16.04

- UPDATE

Thanks for the response.

I expected that when I run Django with runserver command PyPy will keep the optimized path on memory after some warm-up time because it's long-running process. But as you can see in the uploaded image, it doesn't keep optimized path and use interpreter instead of JIT. I want to know why PyPy repeats this behavior and how can we resolve it to use PyPy on our production server.

- [First image from vmprof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzN8F.png)
- [After 1min from vmprof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbFF8.png)

Comment: Could you please improve your post, so that it contains a question? Are you looking for an explanation why the system behaves like it does, or for a way to change the behavior?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "JIT coverage goes to zero".  Can you be more precise---e.g. explain what you observe, and how you think it should be different?  For example, do you mean something like: "if I run this script for a long period of time, then I stop it, then I look at the vmprof output, and what it tells me is that it runs only 2% of the time inside the JIT"?